# Required attribute not validating on a select element

Tags: html

For some reason, the `required` attribute didn't work. Where did I go wrong?

I've already tried putting another `<option>` with blank `value`

```
<form action="">
    <select required>
        <optgroup label="test">
            <option value="">choose</option>
            <option value="red">red</option>
            <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
            <option value="green">green</option>
            <option value="grey">grey</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works without `optgroup` [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h81ofr6z/1/)

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <select required>
      <option value="">choose</option>
      <option value="red">red</option>
      <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
      <option value="green">green</option>
      <option value="grey">grey</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Anyway, there is poor support of the `required` [attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_required.asp) in browsers

Comment: thanks. its working! but is there any alternative for `optgroup`? because i would like to group something. for example. shirt sizes. I'd like to group the sizes for men and women.

Comment: I think the best way is to use JS for validation forms instead of HTML5. So you will able to use `optgroup`